# how do you delete a previous echo / form PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

I am currently working on a project that controls output through an EOT. But when I want to request a new control he puts the new control under the previous control (or under the previous echo). Now I am trying to delete or overwrite the previous echo. I know there are already several topics about it, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to delete my previous echo's when I request my new check through my button. I've already tried with "OB_clean" and "OB_Flush" working in all possible places, but this won't work

Thx!

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="myForm" class="container-fluid">
        <form id="myForm" method="POST">
            <p class="Titel">Controles opvragen:</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button name="Controle1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">Controle 1</button>
                    <button name="Controle2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="2">Controle 2</button>
                    <button name="Controle3" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="3">Controle 3</button>
                    <button name="Controle4" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="4">Controle 4</button>
                    <button name="Controle5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="5">Controle 5</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php
                        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle1'])) 
                        {
                        
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle1'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID) ; 
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle2'])) 
                        {
                          
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle2'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID);      
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle3'])) 
                        {
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle3'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID);  
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle4'])) 
                        {
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle4'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID); 
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle5'])) 
                        {
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle5'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID); 
                        }
                        if (isset($_POST['Controle6'])) 
                        {
                            $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle6'];
                            FormBuilder($checkpointID);
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post text and not images.

Comment: What was echoed once, can not be undone. You could use ob_start() to capture at first and then, if required ob_clean().

Comment: _"I've already tried with "OB_clean" and "OB_Flush" working in all possible places, but this won't work"_ [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67592488/edit) to show where and how you tried.

Comment: It's not even clear what you mean by "delete previous echo". It seems to me that you're describing a regular old change of page content, which should be achievable through normal form submission. Can you please give a concrete example of what you want to happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a form so the page refreshes and clears everytime you click a button and this question has no sense. Anyway, if thats what you need, one way around can be to use jquery to clear. You can give the div an id and use simple jquery to clear everything inside the element. You can echo the jquery code or you can create a function to call when you need with an echo.
There is an example of the code.

```
<script>
     function cleardiv(){
        $("#div").html("");
    }
 </script>
 <div class="content">
   <div id="myForm" class="container-fluid">
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <p class="Titel">Controles opvragen:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button name="Controle1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">Controle 1</button>
                <button name="Controle2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="2">Controle 2</button>
                <button name="Controle3" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="3">Controle 3</button>
                <button name="Controle4" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="4">Controle 4</button>
                <button name="Controle5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="5">Controle 5</button>
            </div>
            <div id="div">
                <?php
                    echo "<script> cleardiv() </script>";
                    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle1'])) 
                    {
                    
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle1'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID) ; 
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle2'])) 
                    {
                      
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle2'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID);      
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle3'])) 
                    {
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle3'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID);  
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle4'])) 
                    {
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle4'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID); 
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle5'])) 
                    {
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle5'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID); 
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['Controle6'])) 
                    {
                        $checkpointID = $_POST['Controle6'];
                        FormBuilder($checkpointID);
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I know that probably this is not the right way to do it but it can be an option.

Comment: Thanks man! This was exactly what I was looking for !!